# Como conectar com banco de dados SQLite que já existe usando PDO?

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados, pdo, sqlite

Desejo conectar com um banco de dados que já existe utilizando PDO e sqlite em PHP, e aqui está o código que tenho:

```
class Database extends PDO{

     public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct("sqlite: userquestion.db");

        $this->exec("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;"); // enable foreign keys
    }
}
```

Porém, quando instancio essa classe, ele cria um novo arquivo `userquestion.db`, ao invés de simplesmente abrir conexão com o arquivo existente.

PS: Já verifiquei e estou utilizando o nome e diretório corretamente.

Comment: Ele está escrevendo por cima do existente? Será que há algum problema de compatibilidade de versão? A documentação fala alguma coisa sobre isto. http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php. Duvido que seja problema mas será que o espaço em branco antes do nome afeta alguma coisa? Na documentação ele pega o `realpath("userquestion.db")` antes de usar o nome do arquivo, será que não é isto? Você fala que o diretório está correto. Tem certeza?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Segundo o exemplo disponível na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php) o arquivo deve ser acessado por seu endereço absoluto, então o nome precisa ser normalizado para ter o [caminho completo absoluto](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php).

```
class Database extends PDO {
     public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct("sqlite:" . realpath("userquestion.db"));
        $this->exec("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;"); // enable foreign keys
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Database/ConnectionSqlite.php).

É claro que também é possível escrever o caminho completo absoluto manualmente e não usar a função `realpath()`. Só o nome do arquivo sem o caminho parece falhar.

Acho menos provável que este seja o problema mas a documentação recomenda o uso do `PRAGMA legacy_file_format = TRUE;` para compatibilizar versões mais novas do SQLite com o PDO (que por sinal costuma ter tantas desvantagens quanto vantagens).